# Error when use get_the_id in inside get_attached_file wordpress

Tags: wordpress

whenever i try to use get_the_ID() inside get_attached_file( ) i always get blank response example `get_attached_file( get_the_ID() )`

but if i use normal number like `get_attached_file( 4125 )` its totaly work

what should i do for fix it ?

my code now :

```html
switch ($command) {
    case 'list_product':

        $loop = new WP_Query( 
                array(
                        'post_type'    => 'product'
                    )
                ); 
        if( $loop->have_posts() ) :

            $data = array( "api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success");
            // First we get the image id
            // $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ); 

            // // Then we get the image data, we will get an array with some informations
            // $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'large' );

            // // the image url is the first index of this array
            // $image_url = $image[0];

            $meta = array();
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                    $meta[] = array(
                        "id"            => get_the_ID(),
                        "post_name"     => get_the_title(),
                        "stock_status"  => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_stock_status', true ),
                        "price"         => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true ),
                        "reguler_price" => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true ),
                        // "image"          => basename( get_attached_file( $post_id ) ),
                    );
            endwhile;
        endif;
        echo  json_encode($meta);
        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/how-to-get-all-image-attachment-post-ids-linked-to-a-wp-post-for-which-i-have-the-post-id-with-me?sul=b&utm_expid=3606929-90.6a_uo883STWy99lnGf8x1g.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.tw%2F) see if this works:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( 
                array(
                        'post_type'    => 'product'
                    )
                ); 
        if( $loop->have_posts() ) :

            $data = array( "api_status" => 1, "api_message" => "success");
            // First we get the image id
            // $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ); 

            // // Then we get the image data, we will get an array with some informations
            // $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'large' );

            // // the image url is the first index of this array
            // $image_url = $image[0];

            $meta = array();
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                    //get the first attachment. Not sure if this is the one you want
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'numberposts' => -1,
                        'post_status' => null,
                        'post_parent' => $post->ID
                     );

                    $attachments = get_posts( $args );   
                    $attachment_ID = $attachments[0]->ID;    

                    $meta[] = array(
                        "id"            => get_the_ID(),
                        "post_name"     => get_the_title(),
                        "stock_status"  => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_stock_status', true ),
                        "price"         => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true ),
                        "reguler_price" => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true ),
                        "image"         => basename( get_attached_file( $attachment_ID ) ),
                    );
            endwhile;
```

Comment: i use `product` ( regular ) as post_type. can i use two post_type for 1 query ?

Comment: hmm, sorry sir, iam still get blank response in `image`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to assign the ID to a variable first -

```
$meta = array();
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    $ID = get_the_ID()
                    $meta[] = array(
                        "id"            => $ID,
                        "post_name"     => get_the_title(),
                        "stock_status"  => get_post_meta( $ID, '_stock_status', true ),
                        "price"         => get_post_meta( $ID, '_price', true ),
                        "reguler_price" => get_post_meta( $ID, '_regular_price', true ),
                        "image"         => basename( get_attached_file( $ID ) ),
                    );
            endwhile;
```

Comment: I've tried it before I post my problem, and in fact the tips u give to me its doesnt work, did  have other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `$post` variable global and use `$post->ID` instead of `$ID` or `get_the_id`, Hope this help